# Hide shortcodes content from the excerpt?

Tags: shortcode

I want to remove every single shortcode from the excerpt.
It looks bad, and I would rather have empty excerpt than one that strips shortcodes for example if I have:

```
[short]OKAY[/short]
```

my search results, visual composer excerpt shows:

```
OKAY
```

I want it to show nothing, nor shortcode nor content in it.
Whats function for this, I lost 1h googling but all I found is not what I want to do.

Comment: Can you give us more details.   I don't understand why there would be shortcodes showing in your excerpt.

Comment: Did you tried using `strip_shortcode()`?